# Unable to push to organization repository as owner

Tags: git, github, github-organizations

I recently created an organization and a repository in that organization. I was successfully able to clone the repository, upload files to it from within GitHub, and use GitHub Desktop to push changes.

However, when I try to `git push origin master` I find that I have `Permission denied`. This is strange as I'm able to do so from GitHub Desktop and I have owner access to the organization and admin access to the repository.

If I try to run `git push origin master` I find that I'm forbidden to do so, despite being logged in with the correct GitHub account (according to `git config --list` and the error message).

```
emote: Permission to Gate-of-Jade/chinese-resource-app.git denied to Destaq.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Gate-of-Jade/chinese-resource-app.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Contents of `.git/config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[submodule]
    active = .
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/Gate-of-Jade/chinese-resource-app.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Is there anything I'm missing or any way to be able to push from the command line as I've tried to do?

Comment: Did you try with the ssh link of the repository?(for origin)

Comment: @GauthamM could you please explain how to do so, I don't think I did because I've never done so before.

Comment: I am not sure whether that would work or not. Currently the url for origin is https. Similarly there would be an ssh link which would be available in the repository page itself. But before that we need to setup ssh keys. You need to generate an ssh key and add it to github.

Comment: I'm also reading that it is **strongly recommended** not to use SSH @GauthamM

Comment: But i think it is more secure. Any specific reason why it is strongly not recommended?

Comment: @GauthamM Actually it is just recommended, not strongly recommended, I think I was thinking of something else.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use

I will try to push with SSH and see if that works.

Comment: @GauthamM I'm having trouble with the SSH. I believe that I have set it up correctly, but pushing still fails. Do you know if there's any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is it showing the same error?

Comment: Yes. However, I've managed to bypass this and get it working by disabling all OAuth restrictions. This is less than ideal, as members with strange OAuth apps could bring the repository harm, but seems to support git pushing from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Destaq, this may be because of not having your SSH or Personal OAuth token keys on your local systems or not present in the Organisation profile, IDK but that's the main reason. So, do check this doc page for help! [Managing Git Access on Organisations](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-git-access-to-your-organizations-repositories)

Comment: Turns out it was because I needed to disable OAuth2 application blocking! Thanks!